# get a key press in bash, but not show it on the screen, or backspace over it, or delete it in script

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard

Sounds wierd I guessm vut what it has a purpose.  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 which has a bug.  It does not save the setting for the brightness of a backlit laptop screen, so every time I boot up, it is way to bright.  I found you can install xbacklight which sets you set the brightness, but you have to run it every reboot, and sometimes after every logout.

I can inc and dec the brightness between 0 and 100 percent, and have scripted this so the user can go up or down using the +/- keya, or even the +/_ settiings of those keys.  And I echo the current setting to the screen so the user can make the setting permanent by modifying the original use of xbacklight -set $VAR.  It works. But...

But when the user presses the key, I see the character automatically on the screen, so I see things like =30 =31 =32 =33 ... -86 -85 -84 -83 -82 ... and this is annoying.  I don't want to see the character, just the percentage.  I tried redirecting stdout and stderr, but this is going right to the screen, so they have no effect.  I considered sending a BS or DEL code to my own stdin, but I don;t know how to do that.  I either need a different method of reading the stdin besides read -n 1 VAR, or some means of ridding myself of the displayed character once it is on the screen.

Could be a good lesson here, if you wanted to script a password acceptance routine that overwrites a typed character with a "*", or better yet, the characters "1" to "9" or "a" to "z" so they can tell how many characters they have entered so far.  But you have to allow them to backspace/delete there as well, so the removed characters have to be overwritten by spaces.

Comment: You have a script outputting those values and you don't want to see them? So edit the script to not output them? How are they "going right to the screen"?

Comment: If they don't reroute with &1> &2> or &> redirectives, then they are not using stdout or stderr as their means of getting to the screen.  That's what I mean by going right to the screen.

Comment: Standard output is going to the screen/tty eventually that's true but that's not "right to the screen" if they are using the normal standard output target and not a direct fd to the tty. In which case you should be able to redirect them anywhere you like. I still don't understand though. If your script is writing the output and you don't want the output then edit the script not to create the output in the first place.

Comment: If they don't redirect, then all I  know is that it isn't behaving as stdout or stderr.  What it is instead I don't know.  But I was able to copy it from the screen using the mouse to highlight and Ctrl+Shft+C to get it to the clipboard.  I got the sources.list file edited and commented out the one line that induced four separate duplicate entry error messages, so it is not a the top of my list anymore.

Comment: You say you _have scripted this_. If you have a script that doesn't work as it should, you should show it in order to enable us to identify the problem.